# Nonlinear system of equation in R packages

Tags: r, package

Can anybody help to give some name of the R packages which will able to solve non-linear system of equation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good tool : nlstools,available @ [http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=nlstools](http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=nlstools.) ,
Needs attention in modeling but can provide help in fitting the model by trial and error.

Example in an application as well as explanation of "how-to" you can find in the doc :
[www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v066i05/v66i05.pdf](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v066i05/v66i05.pdf)

Hope that is of help,
Cheers!